# How to properly use the webkit delegate to start and stop a spinner, OS X, OBJ-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4.5

It seems like this should be so simple, but I am pretty new at Objective-C. What I want to do is simply start and stop a spinner while my WebView is loading. This is an OS X app. Everything I have searched for is for Cocoa Touch, I am using just Cocoa. In my AppDelegate.m I have to methods that start and stop the spinner (This does work, I tested it).

```
-(IBAction)goSpin:(id)sender
{
    [spinner startAnimation:self];
}

-(IBAction)stopSpin:(id)sender
{
    [spinner stopAnimation:self];
}
```

I also have the two delegate methods for webView, which I overrode.

```
-(void)webView:(WebView *)sender didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
{
    [self goSpin:self];
}

-(void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
{
    [self stopSpin:self];
}
```

Basically, I would like to know how I get my webView to set it's delegate. Usually I have to do something in the .h file, but I can't find any references that list what the webKit delegate is that would work for this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The

```
-(void)webView:(WebView *)sender didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
```

and

```
-(void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
```

methods are part of the [WebFrameLoadDelegate Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebFrameLoadDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

[WebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has a `frameLoadDelegate` property. Set it on your `WebView` instance by calling `[webView setFrameLoadDelegate:delegate]`, where `delegate` is an NSObject that implements the two methods (it will be easiest for you to make `self` the frameLoadDelegate here). Since WebFrameLoadDelegate is an informal protocol, `delegate` should declare the two methods in its .h file, rather than add `<WebFrameLoadDelegate>` to its class declaration as with a formal protocol.

Comment: I'll award your bounty in three hours.

Comment: Actually. As this has costs me a lot, I would also like to know how to check the progress of a load. So that I can display a progress bar, instead of a spinner. Thanks. If you don't know how, just tell me. You really do deserve the 50 rep.

Comment: From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html): `... to monitor load progress ... observe the WebViewProgressEstimateChangedNotification, WebViewProgressFinishedNotification, and WebViewProgressStartedNotification notifications. For example, you could observe these notifications to implement a simple progress indicator in your application. You update the progress indicator by invoking the estimatedProgress method to get an estimate of the amount of content that is currently loaded.`

Comment: Not sure if it's a compiler change or something but I absolutely had to add `<WebFrameLoadDelegate>` into the class declaration and then I could compile it.  If I didn't, I couldn't compile the code with `[webView setFrameLoadDelegate:self]` for some reason.

Answer (score -3):

You can override these webview delegate methods to start and stop a spinner.

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

// In this method you have to start a spinner.

}
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

   // In this method you have to stop the current  spinner.


}
 - (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{

      // In this method you have to stop the current  spinner.


 }
```

Comment: That does not work. Those work for Cocoa Touch only. I am using pure Cocoa, OS X. It uses WebView, not UIWebView. The Webkit is slightly different. I don't have those delegates.

Comment: I have searched all over Stack Overflow, along with other sites, but all answers have to do with Cocoa Touch. It's pretty annoying. I really need to figure out how to do this though.